# Determining the host of a web site

Tags: web-hosting

I know that I can find out the registrar for "foobar.com" by running `whois foobar.com`. How can I find out who is hosting a web site? What would indicate, for instance, whether a web site is hosted on someone's home computer?

Comment: Normally whois's provide hosting detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use sites such as whoishostingthis.com to determine the host.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing definitive, but you can [lookup the DNS hostname](http://network-tools.com) of the server's IP address. If you get something like 123-123-123-123.cox.net, that's probably an at-home server. On the other hand if you get something like corpweb-v101.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net, well, that's Godaddy.